# how to qr code generator with multiple info

Tags: android, qr-code

I'm trying to create a QR code with multiple textfields in my Android application. Of which if scanned, I can get all the user information.
I've tried various libraies but it appears that they all allow only one textfield..
Is there any way to genetrate QR code with multiple textfields ??

thanks.

Comment: QR codes encode a single piece of text. If you are expecting other apps to be able to use your barcodes, you should create text that adheres to [one of the existing text formats popularly used for QR codes](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents). If your app is the only one that will use your QR codes, then you can use JSON, XML, CSV, etc. to represent multiple pieces of information in that text.

Answer (score 2):

One of the approaches you can use is converting your data into JSON and loading that JSON as a string into your QR Code. When you scan it, you decode the data back from JSON.

You can use [GSON library](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md) to manage JSON.

Usage:

```
//Encode
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(1);            // ==> 1
gson.toJson("abcd");       // ==> "abcd"
gson.toJson(new Long(10)); // ==> 10
int[] values = { 1 };
gson.toJson(values);       // ==> [1]
```

```
//Decode
int one = gson.fromJson("1", int.class);
Integer one = gson.fromJson("1", Integer.class);
Long one = gson.fromJson("1", Long.class);
Boolean false = gson.fromJson("false", Boolean.class);
String str = gson.fromJson("\"abc\"", String.class);
String[] anotherStr = gson.fromJson("[\"abc\"]", String[].class);
```